# Bring back buffering for HTML5 Video

Tags: google-chrome, video, html5, safari

My internet connection is unrealiable out in the boonies.

Ever since a couple years ago, everyone moved to "instant playback" for video.

Now when I pause a video, it won't buffer for more than 15 seconds.

I want to reload/buffer until the end so I can watch the video without interuptions.

How do you bring back buffering? I tried on chrome/firefox/safari, windows mac and linux.

Not a single modern web browser buffers video. I have to go back to super old firefox to do it.

Answer (score 1):

In [Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1168957):

- Enter *about:config* in the URL bar and accept the warning.
- Type *media.cache* in the configuration Search edit to list a few settings.
- Increase *media.cache_readhead_limit* from the default *60*, up to *9999*.
- Increase *media.cache_resume_treshold* from the default *30*, up to *9999*.